# I put a debugger to my existing windows application attached to process and I am puzzled by the output

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBar',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Orientation; DataItem=null;
>   target element is 'VsMenuItem' (Name=''); target property is
>   'NoTarget' (type 'Object') System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find
>   source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBar',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DockLocation;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'VsMenuItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object') System.Windows.Data Error: 4 :
>   Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBar',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DockLocation;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'VsMenuItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you add a lot more information and format your post please. At present, the question is just an error trace and therefore meaningless.

Comment: Sounds like you are debugging a Visual Studio instance. Are you developing a VS extension? How does `sql-server-2008` fit into this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer for this, because I have to set the app.config files string connection to the correct database, but it always cannot find the path, so I get the directory path of the app.config and hardcoded it in my code.